# What does np.reshape(-1) do

Tags: python, numpy

I am aware of what -1 in one of the reshape dimensions does, when the other dimension is provided - say a.reshape(2,-1) ( numpy calculates the dimension for -1, based on the original array and the other dimension specified).

But, I am not sure what a.reshape(-1) does. can some one please explain

Comment: It just flattens the array

Comment: What have you tried that you don't understand ? It'll be easier to explain if you put here the lines of code that seem weird to you. :)

Comment: For reference, [`np.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) / [`np.ndarray.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) is an equivalent function. The reshape works the same as in the case of two dimensions. You have a single dimension, that is automatically calculated as the total size of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that is just returns the flattened array, regardless of the initial shape.

```
x = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))
y = x.reshape(-1)
y.shape
(27,)
y
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26])
x = np.arange(10)
y = x.reshape(-1)
y
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Also, make sure your new shape argument to reshape is a tuple, i.e. a.reshape((2, -1)).