# reshaping data in numpy with (-1,1). What does it mean?

Tags: numpy-ndarray

I get from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57417883/6861378 what `np.reshape(-1)` does. It's reshaping it into 1D array. But what about (a,(-1,1))?

```
a_concat = np.reshape(a,(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`reshape(-1)` is a line vector, when `reshape(-1,1)` is a column:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.linspace(1,6,6).reshape(2,3)
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])
>>> a.shape
(2, 3)
>>> a.reshape(-1)
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.])
>>> a.reshape(-1,1)
array([[ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 5.],
       [ 6.]])
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much. I'm sorry I was late responding